# Android Oreo foreground service not work in Doze mode

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

To overcome the android OREO (targetSdkVersion 27) background service limitation, I have created a foreground service with Notification. Notification is showing in notification bar and so far the service is running. I have put my code related to Activity Recognition and Location Tracking using FusedLocationClient in the foreground service class. The ActivityRecognition and Location Tracking are working as expected when the phone is active or the screen is on. But they don’t work when the screen is off or in Doze mode. I am not sure whether I am misunderstanding the Android documentation that there should not have any limitation while using Foreground Service with visible Notification.

My primary target is to get user Activity Status and Location record on maximum 1/2 minutes interval. But my current foreground service provides location and activity fewer times and it only returns when the device screen is ON. 
By the way, my foreground service is not a bound service and I start the service using following code:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(_context, ForegroundLocationService.class);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(_context.getApplicationContext(),startIntent);
```

I am calling above code using a helper class which is called from MainApplication (extends Application) class, not from any activity class.

So, in OREO what else I have to do to achieve my target, please suggest me.

Comment: Having a foreground service does not affect [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

Comment: Is there any way around to overcome the Doze mode limitation? I have no problem to show notification or authorization warning to users as my app is targeted to a small group of specific business/corporate users.

Comment: By the way, I have disabled the battery optimization for my app, but no luck.

Comment: In the battery optimization screen, is Play Services shown as being not optimized? It should be, and usually that cannot be changed, but it is worth checking. Also, what device are you testing on? Some device manufacturers have their own custom power management stuff. It might also be worth a test to see how your app behaves if another app is accessing locations in the background. For example, you might set up Google Maps for navigation, then move it to the background and see what happens.

Comment: I am using HUAWEI handset and I have set "Manage manually" in Launch option under battery optimization. Manage manually should allow auto launch, run in background and launch by other app. But I think they are not working.

Comment: Huawei devices have a reputation for being difficult for developers, particularly with respect to background work.

Comment: @CommonsWare In regards to DOZE, does it make no difference if my service is background or foreground?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: I don't think so. That affects other stuff, particularly starting with Android 8.0 (can't run longer than a minute otherwise), but I don't think it affects Doze. It will affect app standby, IIRC, as since you are visible to the user by means of the `Notification`, you shouldn't go into app standby mode (at least prior to 9.0, where they switched to this bucket system that I haven't memorized just yet...).

Comment: @CommonsWare I've played around with adb after writing this comment and actually having a foreground service keeps the wakelock active when the device falls into doze, whereas a background service's wakelock gets disabled.

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I am also facing the same. Activity Recognition and location tracking is not working when the device(Specific to Huawei) screen is off.

Comment: @FlorianWalther: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @HabiburRahman did you found any solution to it? I'm facing the same problem in the Huawei device in my Multi Timer App.